# Is this the angular way to keep track of checked items?

Tags: angularjs

I have achieved what I want, which is to create an array of all checked items in angular. I plan to use these in another function.

My solution feels a bit awkward, is there a better way to do this?

```
<input 
    ng-repeat="task in $store.taskarr track by $index" 
    ng-change="checked(check,$index,task)" 
    ng-model="check" 
    type="checkbox" 
/>


$scope.checked = function(check,count,task){
    if(check){
        $scope.$store.checkedItems[count] = task;
    }else{
        delete $scope.$store.checkedItems[count];
    }
}
```

Comment: The implementation is fine, it's hard to say if there is a better way, it depends on how `checkedItems` is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I liked this as it's using less code:

```
        <input 
            ng-repeat="task in $store.taskarr track by $index" 
            ng-change="check ? ($store.checkedItems[$index] = task) :
                ($store.checkedItems[$index] = undefined)"
            ng-model="check" 
            type="checkbox" 
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of a service that tracks the state of selected items and an attribute directive you can attach to the checkbox.

The data can be modeled as an object that maps IDs to whether or not an item is checked.

The directive controller can handle the responsibility of updating the service so your parent controllers don't have to care about that part, but you can still get the selection state from anywhere in your app.